# Express session create a new session every request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

I am trying to create my fullstack application. I need to set up the correct session to let user login to a given space. In that page, if you have no the right of login, you get relocated to the login form.

So, I do the login with correct credentials, it calls the backend that theoretically makes the login, setting a session variable to a given username, and send back that he succeded.

If he did, the page of destinations opens. The problem is that this page continues to make the check if it is logged, but it always find out that it isn't, even if it has been just logged.
That happens because the session id of the requests are different every time. THe session does not expire, because it ends in 24h, and the session id printed from both the call is different.

I used to think that a session was property of the browser it self, so I was sure that there were no problem in splitting into different pages. I don't know if that is the issue.

Here are the code of all the files

Login.js:

```
formL.addEventListener("submit", async function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let username = document.getElementById("nome").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("psw").value;
    if (username == "" || password == "") {
        error.style.display = "block";
        error.innerHTML = `<p>Fullfill all the pitches</p>`
    }else{
        await fetch('http://localhost:5000/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: username,
                password: password
            })
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data =>{
                if(data.logged == "true"){
                    setTimeout(changePage,1000);//sert timeout to let API refresh
                }else{
                    //set error div
                }
            }
        )
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }
});

function changePage(){
    window.location.href = "./insert.html";
}
```

Page.js:

```
const getData = async () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/logged")//'https://mad4feltre.herokuapp.com/logged'
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(data['logged'] === 'false'){
                alert(data.logged)
                location.replace(`./login.html`)
            }
        });
```

Server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');

//Import enviromental variabiles
require('dotenv').config();

//Get one day in milliseconds
const oneDay = 86400000;

//Initializing
const app = express(); 
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.set('trust proxy', 1)

//Setup session and cookie
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    saveUninitialized:true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
        sameSite: 'none'
    },
    resave: false 
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(cookieParser());

//Let imported functionality working
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());

//Routes
const router = require('./routes/router');
app.use('',router);

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port:${port}`);
});
```

Router.js:

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.sessionID)
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    let session = req.session;

    try {
        const user = await pool.query(
            `SELECT * FROM utente WHERE username= ($1) AND password = MD5($2)`, [username, password]
        );

        if(user.rows.length != 0){
            session.userid=req.body.username;
            res.json({'logged':'true'});
        }else{
            res.json({'logged':'false', 'error':'uncorrect username or password'});
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});

router.get('/logged',(req,res) => {
    console.log(req.sessionID)
    session=req.session;

    if(session.userid){
        res.send({'logged':'true'});
    }else{
        res.send({'logged':'false'});
    }
});
```

If you know how I can fix that,  would be really appreciated. Thank you a lot.

I could merge the files, but there is a lot of more code in the projects, and there would be a lot of problems in my opinion

Comment: Per the duplicate your question has been marked of, you need `credentials: 'include'` on your `fetch()` call so that the session cookie is included with each request.  Without that, the session cookie is not sent and express-session just thinks it's a brand new client every time and keeps making a new sessionID.

Comment: Yes, but now I have problems with CORS. It tells me that I need to change access-control-allow-origin. I Do that but it doesn't work

Comment: Well, that's a completely different issue which is not part of this question at all as you don't even mention that in the original question or provide any information about it.  I'd suggest you write a new question about the CORs issues.  Explain what origin your web page is, show the client and server code that has the CORs issue.  Show exactly what the debug console in the browser shows and show what you tried to fix it.  Also, there are over a thousand CORs questions and answers here on SO, so you can probably also find your solution with a good search here.